# How to deactivate the flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, builder

When I am attempting to create a flow its showing an error maximum flow reached. Is there any way we can deactivate the existing workflows?

Comment: try if you can merge some workflows.

Answer (score 0):

If its visual flow and you dont need that flow anymore you can click go to "View Details and Version" from the flow list view action and can deactivate the latest version which is active. 
If it is workflow rule you can directly deactivate from the list view.

If you want the functionality of the flow/workflow then you have to try to merge with existing one which is over the same object

Answer (score 0):

Here are the governor limits with Flows.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_flow_limits.htm

in case you are not reaching the object limit or overall flow limit, and reaching the max versions in a single flow then you can

- in LEX, you can view the flow record and choose view details and
  versions from the context menu and delete some old versions of the
  same flow
- in classic, you can view the details of the flow and then
  view all the previous versions of the flow.